# I get error when trying to deploy MERN app to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, git, heroku

I am following a MERN stack tutorial by Traversy Media, I am currently trying to deploy to Heroku.  But whenever I try to `git push heroku master`, it gives me this:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mern-shopping-list-available.git'
```

I followed every step, making sure I did everything correctly.
Here is my GitHub with the code:
https://github.com/Stick-z/MERN-Shopping

Here is the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71wSzpLyW9k&list=PLillGF-RfqbbiTGgA77tGO426V3hRF9iE&index=8

Comment: You forgot a start script in your package.json, probably unrelated but it will save you the hassle later.

Comment: I don't know if this count as a start script, but my dev script runs both the client and server.